# How to Read number of lines in text file from int to int JAVA

Tags: file, java.util.scanner

So the problem i'm having is that the code is reading the text files from line 1-3, I want it to read the text files from line 3-5. I have the code set up and What I need to figure out how to do is have it start at line 3, its currently reading 3 lines which is good but since it doesnt start at 3 it doesnt read the right lines and output them

Here is my code so far

```
  public void display(int from, int to) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    File f = new File(fileName);
    if (f.exists()) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine() && from <= to){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            from++;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("This File Does Not Exist");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}

It is currently giving me the output
"1-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2-Consectetuer adipiscing elit
3-Sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt"

which is the files of my text, When in reality i need it to start at line three and thats all I need help with

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You don't write Java code with an image editor, you write it with a text editor, which means that it can be copied and pasted directly into your question. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the  [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Regarding the issue you're having, read lines 1 and 2 and throw them away, and then read the next three lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help! sorry for using an image I couldn't figure out how to use the code block but will fix that up.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a loop and ignore the first two lines you don't want to read

```java
for (int i = 0; i < from-1; i++) {
   if (sc.hasNextLine()) sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Never-mind, I got it to work! I did it a little differently though, instead of 0 and 2 i made the values my variables "from" and "to" so that no matter what i input it will skip the correct amount of lines. Thank you so much for your help!!